# React. Prevent click events on Double click

Tags: reactjs, double-click, react-custom-hooks

Im trying to implement a timer to distinguish between single click and dbl click events so the single click does not fire when dbl clicking.

Edit: I should clarify, I want the component to react differently to single/double clicks, the Double click is working, but when I double click it also fires a single click event.  I want to ignore the single click when during a double click

```
export const useNoClickOnDblClick = (onClick: () => void, onDoubleClick: () => void) => {
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let singleClickTimer: string | number | NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;
    if (clicks === 1) {
      singleClickTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        onClick();
        setClicks(0);
      }, 250);
    } else if (clicks === 2) {
      onDoubleClick();
      setClicks(0);
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(singleClickTimer);
  }, [clicks]);

  return {
    clicks,
    setClicks
  };
};
```

Not sure if this is the best way, but I came across this implementations near the bottom of this thread, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3185

It seems to work for basic usage, functions that have no parameters, like below

```
  const { setClicks } = useNoClickOnDblClick(handleRenderInfo, () => console.log('dbl click'));


 <SummaryCard
   data={data}
   onCardClick={() => setClicks((prev) => prev + 1)}
 />
```

However I want to do something like this, where I need to pass in different data for each card

```
 const { setClicks } = useNoClickOnDblClick(handleRenderLevelInfo, () => console.log('dbl click'));

{mineData.levelArr.map((level, i) => {
        return (
          <MineCard
            key={i}
            data={level}
            onCardClick={() => setClicks((prev) => prev + 1)}
            //onCardClick={() => handleRenderLevelInfo({ ...level, idx: i })}
            onCardDblClick={() =>
              navigateTo({ path: `/${surveyPointsPrefix}/${mineID}/${level.level}` })
            }
          />
        );
      })}
```

How do I go about passing in the level data from the .map?  I know I can pass the entire thing into the customHook along with the single/double click, But I feel like it will get pretty messy if I  am trying to reuse the hook etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think `NodeJS.Timeout` does any sense on client side.

Comment: Have you looked into this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event

Answer (score 0):

```
singleClickMethod () {};
doubleClickMethod () {};

hasDoubleClick = false:

onClickHandler (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    setTimeout(() => {
        if (hasDoubleClick) {
            hasDoubleClick = false;
            return;
        }

        singleClickMethod();
    });
};

onDblClickHandler () {
    hasDoubleClick = true;

    doubleClickMethod();
}
```

Such approach is going to work for you and distinguish the click events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom hook:

```
export const useDoubleClick = (onClick, onDbClick, delay = 300) => {
  const timePassed= useRef(0);
  return (e) => {
   if (e.detail === 1) {
     setTimeout(() => {
       if (Date.now() - timePassed.current >= delay) {
         onClick();
       }
     }, delay)
   }

   if (e.detail === 2) {
     timePassed.current = Date.now();
     onDbClick();
   }
 }
}
```

And in then use it like this:

```
const onClick = () => console.log('click')
const onDoubleClick = () => console.log('double click')

const myDoubleClickCallback = useDoubleClick(onClick, onDoubleClick);
```

And add myDoubleClickCallback to the component:

```
<div onClick={myDoubleClickCallback}>Click Me</div>
```

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jovial-water-hhs75d?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A16%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpb4m6s80007356l0sg58blo%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpb4m6s80003356ltftxhlvd%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpb4m6s80004356l5tmkvkmy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpb4m6s80006356lcknt5n6f%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpb4m6s80003356ltftxhlvd%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpb4m6s80003356ltftxhlvd%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpb4ww330003356km2cwugrp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A16%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A16%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpb4ww330003356km2cwugrp%2522%257D%252C%2522clpb4m6s80006356lcknt5n6f%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpb4m6s80005356lh7uxnoge%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpb4m6s80006356lcknt5n6f%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpb4m6s80005356lh7uxnoge%2522%257D%252C%2522clpb4m6s80004356l5tmkvkmy%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpb4m6s80004356l5tmkvkmy%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)